# PCRE regex escaping dot for delimiter

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to extract the title from a remote page, this is the regula expression I'm using:

```
$remote_page_title  = preg_match( '#<title>(.*)</title>#i', $remote_page_body, $new_item_title );
die( html_entity_decode( $new_item_title[1] ) );
```

The fact is that, if the title contains a #, it is considered as closing delimiter breaking the regex. Is there any way I can escape the dot character to backslash #?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if the title contains the character `#`, that's not what's breaking your REGEX. Post the entire code please. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/xDxVZS

Comment: See updated example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OgoS83

Comment: I got the correct title returned. Did you try using a different delimiter?

Comment: The title I'm dealing with is
Edit Post &lsaquo; My Plugins &#8212; WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Normally this shouldn't be breaking your regex. Either try different delimiter or try using a greedy match (.+).